# How can I access an subscription_id from database in Laravel without using DB:: method?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to access the `subscription_id` from the subscriptions table from MySQL server, using Laravel.

Except for the `DB::` method, are they any other ways to do it? Thank you!

Comment: I mean Hi everyone, sorry.

Comment: Do you use Eloquent? If so, do you have a Model class for the subscriptions table?

Comment: What do you want to do? An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Eloquent. Fast Example:

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Suscriptions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'suscriptions';
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Suscription;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $var = Suscription::all();

        return view('home')->with('var', $var);
    }

}
```

View

```
@foreach($var as $var)
    {{ $var->suscription_id }}
@endforeach
```

Take a look here in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent